# Unable to setup WebRTC native android code on ubuntu instance

Tags: webrtc

Followed steps provided in this web page https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

When I executed command "ninja -C out/Debug AppRTCMobile" I got following response

> ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
>
> ninja: fatal: chdir to 'out/Debug' - No such file or directory

I got stuck here and need help to continue in executing the next steps to complete the code setup.

Ubuntu version - 16.04.2

I have followed the same procedure once again to setup the code. This time I got a new error

Steps:

> -> fetch --nohooks webrtc_android
>
> -> gclient sync
>
> -> gn gen out/Debug --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'
>
> -> ninja -C out/Debug
>
> ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
>
> [1/8508] ACTION
>   //base:android_runtime_jni_headers__jni_Runtime(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
>
> FAILED: gen/android_runtime_jni_headers/base/jni/Runtime_jni.h python
>   ../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py --depfile
>   gen/base/android_runtime_jni_headers__jni_Runtime.d --jar_file
>   ../../third_party/android_tools/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar
>   --input_file java/lang/Runtime.class --ptr_type=long --output_dir gen/android_runtime_jni_headers/base/jni --includes
>   ../../../../../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator_helper.h
>   --native_exports_optional
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1428,
>   in 
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
>
> File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1421,
>   in main
>       GenerateJNIHeader(input_file, output_file, options)   File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1326, in
>   GenerateJNIHeader
>       jni_from_javap = JNIFromJavaP.CreateFromClass(input_file, options)
>
> File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 662,
>   in CreateFromClass
>       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in
>   _execute_child
>       raise child_exception
>
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>
> [3/8508] CC obj/third_party/boringssl/boringssl/v3_ncons.o
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Someone please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the projects using GN before trying to compile.  You have the instructions here:

https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/